# Listening only for local inbound connections over "clearnet", and using Tor for external connections

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, privacy, tor

I want to connect some wallets to my node in my LAN, over regular connection (not Tor), but I don't want my node to use this "clearnet" connection for anything else (for example to connect to other public nodes). All other (outbound) traffic should be over Tor connection.

Is it possible? What is the proper configuration for this?

Thanks

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. Do you want to connect some *nodes* locally on your LAN, or do you want to connect some *wallets*? If the answer is the latter, wouldn't RPC access suffice for that? Why do you need network access?